# C# GraphQLRequest : Variable $max is used by but not declared

Tags: c#, .net-core, graphql

I'm trying to send a GraphQL Request using [This GraphQL Library](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-client).

When I attempt to send the `GraphQLRequest` with [some variables attached](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-client#operationname-and-variables-request) I get the following error,
`Variable $max is used by but not declared`.

```
GraphQLRequest graphqlRequest = new GraphQLRequest
{
    Query = "query {boards(limit: $max) {items(limit: $max) {id}}}",
    Variables = new
    {
        max = "1"
    }
};

GraphQLResponse<string> graphQLResponse = await _graphqlClient.SendQueryAsync<string>(graphqlRequest);
```

Changing `max` from a string to an int had no change.
If I try and send the same request hardcoded without the `Variables` attached, the request is successful.
`query {boards(limit: 1) {items(limit: 1) {id}}}`
**Update**

I updated the query with the help of gunr2171's answer, however unfortunately the sdk is still throwing errors.

```
GraphQLRequest graphqlRequest = new GraphQLRequest
{
    Query = "query($max: Int) {boards(limit: $max) {items(limit: $max) {id}}}",
    Variables = new
    {
        max = 1
    }
};
```

`System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'data', line 1, position 9.)'`

I tried changing `$max: Int` to `$max: String` as well as `max = 1` to `max = "1"`
but the request isnt sucessful.
`Variable max of type Int was provided invalid value` or `Type mismatch on variable $max and argument limit (String / Int)` depending on the combination.

**Update**

Changing the response type from `string` to the proper object response has solved the problem. eg

```
GraphQLResponse<string> graphQLResponse = await _graphqlClient.SendQueryAsync<string>(graphqlRequest);
```

to

```
GraphQLResponse<AuthorizationResponse> graphQLResponse = await _graphqlClient.SendQueryAsync<AuthorizationResponse>(graphqlRequest);
```

For some one reason or another when using `Variables` it didnt like the string response type.
Thank you gunr2171 for their help, and pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the variable in the top level query before you can use it inside the query body.

```
query($max: Int) {
  boards(limit: $max) {
    items(limit: $max) {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

<sub>New line characters added for readability. You can collapse this to one line for your actual code.</sub>

The difference here is the `($max: Int)` after `query`. That let's the graphql engine know that some variables will be used and what their type is. I'm assuming for your example that the variable is an integer.

---

Also, when you submit your variables, make sure you keep the data as an integer.

```
Variables = new
{
   max = 1 // don't quote this
}
```

You've got three places where the types need to line up correctly.

1. The `Variables` property of the GraphQLRequest
2. The declaration of the variable in `query()`
3. The expected type for the arguments you are using.

Double check that the `limit` arguments of BOTH `boards()` and `items()` is an `Int`, and not for some reason another data type (like String).

Comment: Updated answer, you were sending your variable as a string