# C# How to Properly Consume Yelp GraphQL api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, graphql, yelp

I'm trying to call the business endpoint of Yelp's `GraphQL` api with my `asp.net core mvc` application using `GraphQLHttpClient`. I have the api and `bearer token` configured in my client instance. I followed the query structure [here](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-client) using business as the endpoint and I just wanted Id and Name fields from the data. When I call `SendQueryAsync(query)`, I get a `GraphQL` Error from the response. I'm not sure if I'm making an improper `httprequest` and/or my query is written wrong. I couldn't find any YouTube videos, stackoverflow questions, or github projects regarding consuming Yelp's `GraphQL api` using C#. Any help is appreciated. Thank you! Below is my source code and attached response.

[Update: Resolved Issued]

There were a collection of issues. Added additional required fields with variables to YelpGraphQL query for GraphQL request. More about query structure and variable declaration is explained in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64299685/c-sharp-graphqlrequest-variable-max-is-used-by-but-not-declared). Overrided the casing of the fields (ty Neil). Fixed the responsetype class and added the missing classes (ty Neil). Added searchconsumer class to controller via dependency injection. Also I will post copied text of exceptions next time.

Classes

```
public class Business
{
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Search
{
    [JsonPropertyName("business")]
    public List<Business> business { get; set; }
}

public class SearchResponseType
{
    [JsonPropertyName("search")]
    public Search Search { get; set; }
}

public interface ISearchConsumer
{
    public Task<List<Business>> GetAllBusinesses();
}

public class SearchConsumer : ISearchConsumer
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

    public SearchConsumer(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public async Task<List<Business>> GetAllBusinesses()
    {
        var authorization = _dbContext.Authorizations.FirstOrDefault().Token;
        var _client = new GraphQLHttpClient("https://api.yelp.com/v3/graphql", new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer());
        _client.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authorization);
        var query = new GraphQLRequest
        {
            Query = @"
            query($termId: String $locationId: String){
                search(term:$termId location:$locationId) {
                    business {
                        id
                        name
                    }
                }
            }",
            Variables = new
            {
                termId = "burrito",
                locationId = "san francisco"
            }
        };
        var response = await _client.SendQueryAsync<SearchResponseType>(query);
        var businesses = response.Data.Search.business;
        return businesses;
    }
}
```

Controllers

```
public class YelpGraphQLController : Controller
{
    private readonly ISearchConsumer _consumer;

    public YelpGraphQLController(ISearchConsumer consumer)
    {
        _consumer = consumer;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        var businesses = await _consumer.GetAllBusinesses();
        return Ok(businesses);
    }
}
```

Program

```
ConfigureServices(builder.Services);

void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<ISearchConsumer, SearchConsumer>();
}
```

YelpGraphQL Json Data Example

```
{
  "data": {
    "search": {
      "business": [
        {
          "id": "wGl_DyNxSv8KUtYgiuLhmA",
          "name": "Bi-Rite Creamery"
        },
        {
          "id": "lJAGnYzku5zSaLnQ_T6_GQ",
          "name": "Brenda's French Soul Food"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

[Debug GraphQL Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjuwg.png)

Comment: Can you post the exact error/exception you are getting

Comment: @Neil I don't get an error after my controller get action runs but I posted a the GraphQL debug error. Does that help or are you referring to something else?

Comment: That suggests to me that your response class is not correct.  Paste the JSON response into any JSON to classes web site, and get the correct class definition.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the deserialization isn't working because of the casing of the fields vs your class, which you can override like so:

```
public class Business
{
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseBusinessCollectionType
{
    [JsonPropertyName("businesses")]
    public List<Business> Businesses { get; set; }
}
```